# How can I select first_name , maximum salary group by gender?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables  tab1 and tab2.

```
create table tab1 ( emp_id number(2), salary number(4));

insert into tab1 values(1,2000); 
insert into tab1 values(2,3000); 
insert into tab1 values(3,3645); 
insert into tab1 values(4,2143); 
insert into tab1 values(5,2541);

create table tab2( emp_id number(2), first_name varchar2(20), gender varchar2(10) );

insert into tab2 values(1,'aaaa','male'); 
insert into tab2 values(2,'bbbb','female'); 
insert into tab2 values(3,'cccc','male'); 
insert into tab2 values(4,'dddd','female'); 
insert into tab2 values(5,'eeee','male');
```

I can get only gender and maximum salary column with this query, but I want to see also emp_id and first_name columns as a result. Here is my query...

```
select m.gender,max(h.salary) 
  from tab2 m 
  join tab1 h 
    on m.emp_id=h.emp_id 
 group by m.gender;
```

Comment: Please define your desired output from your sample data. You have several people here who have tried to guess what you want and have posted differently shaped result sets. So some of them have wasted their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is inefficient and unnecessary to read the `tab2` table twice, as in some of the other answers.  You can use what is commonly referred to as `MAX..KEEP`, but what is confusingly documented as the `FIRST` function ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641)).

This query uses the feature to give you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT  t2.gender,
        max(t2.emp_id) keep ( dense_rank first order by t1.salary desc ) emp_id,
        max(t2.first_name) keep ( dense_rank first order by t1.salary desc ) first_name,
        max(t1.salary)
FROM    tab1 t1
INNER JOIN tab2 t2 ON t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id
GROUP BY t2.gender;
```

Notice that it reads each table only once.

Results:

> ```
> +--------+--------+------------+----------------+
> | GENDER | EMP_ID + FIRST_NAME | MAX(T1.SALARY) |
> +--------+--------+------------+----------------+
> | female |      2 + bbbb       |           3000 |
> | male   |      3 + cccc       |           3645 |
> +--------+--------+------------+----------------+
> ```

I will assert that this is the most efficient means of getting the results you seek.

[I don't like to make statements like that without wriggle room (or "weasel words", if you like), since there is so much out there we all need to learn.  But, if there is a faster way to do this query, learning it would be worth enduring a public correction on SO.  :) ]

#### UPDATE

Incidentally, if you had a `GENDERS` table, like this...

```
create table genders ( gender varchar2(10) );

insert into genders values ('male');
insert into genders values ('female');
```

Then this would also be a reasonable solution in 12c and later:

```
select g.gender, 
       ca.emp_id, 
       ca.first_name, 
       ca.salary 
from genders g  
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT t2.emp_id, 
                     t2.first_name, 
                     t2.gender, 
                     t1.salary
              FROM   tab1 t1 
              INNER JOIN tab2 t2 on t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id
              WHERE  t2.gender = g.gender
              ORDER BY t1.salary DESC
              FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY ) ca
```

The benefits of this alternate approach are:

1. less repetition of the `MAX..KEEP` syntax, which can get burdensome if you want not just `emp_id` and `first_name` but a bunch of other columns as well
2. it can benefit from indexes that help the query in the `CROSS APPLY`.  In your case, an index on `GENDER` is not likely to be selective enough to help, but it's something to keep in mind for other situations.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks, but I don't see what you mean.  How is `first_name` "missing"?  It is the 2nd column in the output.

Comment: excuse me, should be `emp_id`

Comment: The MAX..KEEP solution provides a coherent answer with the sample data, especially given there are no ties on max salary. But the result set doesn't make as much sense when there are ties on salary and the EMP_ID and FIRST_NAME don't ascend in lockstep. Which is not to say that this isn't the answer the OP is looking for, just that they haven't clearly specified the required ouput.

Comment: @APC When such ties are possible, they're usually dealt with by specifying a tie-breaker in the `ORDER BY` of each `MAX..KEEP`.  E.g., using `( dense_rank first order by t1.salary desc, t2.first_name asc)` in each one.  It's still a valid approach as long as the requirement is not show ALL the records tied for highest salary in each gender.

Answer (score 2):

Could you need  a join on the saubquery for max sal and gender

```
select  t1.emp_id, , t2.first_name, t.max_sal, t.gender 
from  tab1 t1 
inner join  tab2 t2 on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id 
inner join  (
  select m.gender,max(h.salary) max_sal
  from tab2 m 
  join tab1 h on m.emp_id=h.emp_id 
  group by m.gender

) t on t.max_sal = t1.salary  and t.gender = t2.gender
```

Comment: It gives me an error:
 ORA-00904: tab1.salary : invalid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

select tab2.gender,tab1.salary,tab1.emp_id,tab2.first_name from tab1 join tab2 on tab1.emp_id=tab2.emp_id where tab1.salary=(select max(tab1.salary) from tab1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONc1f.png)